# Receive email from an Exchange server in Biztalk w/o using POP3 or IMAP

Tags: email, biztalk, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I know Biztalk has a POP3 adapter for receiving/processing email, but our network group has disabled both POP3 and IMAP access to our Exchange servers. Since I'm not able to connect using those protocols, I'm looking for other options.

1. Is there some way to connect through OWA? Some kind of API access?
2. Are there any other protocols/adapters that might be useful here?
3. Do I need to petition our network group to open up POP3 access, even if it's only to certain accounts/from certain workstations?
4. (Ugly) Do I install Outlook on the server, and have an Outlook VBA macro process incoming mail and stuff it into a database table, where it can then be processed by Biztalk later?

I'm open to any other ideas - thanks for your help!

**FOLLOWUP:**

We ended up talking the network group into allowing POP3 for the account in question, so we can use the standard Biztalk adapters. However, were we still restricted, the OWA web services seemed to be the only legitimate option, though I'm glad we don't have to go that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exchange has a web service interface that you could use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb408417.aspx

Comment: That looks promising - I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Kayxo BizTalk Exchange Adapter

http://msinnovations.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/kayxo-biztalk-exchange-adapter-tips/

Ups, forget about it, they closed