# Receive email from an Exchange server in Biztalk (no POP3)

Tags: email, smtp, exchange-server, biztalk

I expected Biztalk to have a default Exchange adapter but it doesn't.

Then I expected to find a buyable adapter, [there was one but it disappeard...](http://msinnovations.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/the-changing-biztalk-landscape/#comment-1012)
I googled and end up finding this
[Receive email from an Exchange server in Biztalk w/o using POP3 or IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509852/receive-email-from-an-exchange-server-in-biztalk-w-o-using-pop3-or-imap)

POP3 or EWS are not an option for me. What could I do?

I read a comment sugesting a SMTP redirection, but I would need to install a mail client on the Biztalk Server:

```
     A while ago we ended up installing the SMTP adapter on the BizTalk Server and having 
the exchange server forward the emails to the biztalk server via SMTP, 
    then BizTalk picked up the msg files from the SMTP folders and then we used the mime 
decoder component in a pipeline (plus this trick here 
http://connectedthoughts.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/receiving-mime-encoded-email-files-and-a-hidden-pop3-context-property/) 
to read the emails.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SMTP redirection to something you install on one of your BizTalk servers is IMO an ugly solution if if you care about high availability. I might be wrong, but I would not want to nlb that?

What about the option of the Exchange Webservice interface that were voted up, in the thread you linked to?   Do you have access to do that?

Query the Exchangeserver for a "[FindItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa566107.aspx)"

Comment: +1 You would also need a strategy for polling the exchange web service at regular intervals - these are discussed here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/biztalkr2adapters/thread/09836a07-0b26-4ab1-b1e8-4344950d0c7e. And there is also the Scheduled Task Adapter for trigger messages http://biztalkscheduledtask.codeplex.com/

Comment: As I said EWS (Exchange Web Services) is not an option for now. I'll try and ask again but you know big companies...I use the scheduler adapter right know for another application, works great

Comment: Apols - missed EWS exclusion. Which leaves IMAP (pull) and / or configuring BizTalk to accept SMTP (push) ?